# Tablesorter columns auto-resizable

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-ui-resizable

I have some problems to find how resize automatically my columns to max in tablesorter, I've put the last version (2.15) and tried some things like this:

```
$("#table")
.tablesorter({
    widthFixed: true,
    sortLocaleCompare: true,
    sortList: [ [0,1] ],
    theme : 'bootstrap',
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "uitheme", "resizable"],
    widgetOptions: {
       resizable : true,
       resizable_addLastColumn : true
    }
})
```

My main issue is that I've 57 columns to display and that tablesorter tries to take less space, I just want to put the max width by columns without put a fix width in my code.

Have you some suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean my "max-width"? In the latest version 2.15.12, a new [`resizable_widths` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-resizable-widths) was added; maybe try that.

Comment: I just want that tablesorter takes the max width by cell on each column and applies it. For the new resizable_widths, it's for set it manually the width and I want it to be set automatically.